# Share memory/objects between javascript and native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

Is there a way to share a javascript `object` / java [`WritableMap`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/WritableMap.java) between javascript and native or is the communication always completely serialized?

I tried to  send a `WritableMap` to the JS side and modify it in native/java afterwards.

That gives me an error:

> Receiving map already consumed`